# Changing activity?

Tags: android

I am in my fourth activity and I want to come back to the first activity directly (without closing the second and third activity).
How to change to the activity directly?

Answer (score 4):

Just bring it to front by startActivity(). You may want to add the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to the Intent, depending what behavior you need.